# How to get list of array using predicates in iOS

Tags: ios, predicate

i have an mutable array named Song_info and adding object like

```
        Song *song=[[Song alloc] init];
        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:outURL];
        song.title=title;
        song.album=album;
        song.length=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f MB",ft];
        song.URl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",assetURL];
        [song_info addObject:song];
```

where Song is a NSObject subclass.

how to get  array of  only "url" using predicates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using KVC...

```
[song_info valueForKeyPath:@"Url"]
```

This will give you an array containing only the URLs.